# How to install Metasploit on Mavericks + MacPorts?

Tags: macos, metasploit, install

I would like to install Metasploit on an hardened OS.
For this purpose I chose Mavericks
just because I'm able to harden this OS pretty far.

I would like to install Metasploit with MacPorts because until now, all the best security tools I needed were correctly manageable with MacPorts through 4 different versions of MacOS X (Snow Leopard, Lion, Mountain Lion, Mavericks).
(This installation challenge is part of a baptism by fire.)

I already did this installation on previous versions of this OS.
I also already found pretty good references to install Metasploit on MacOS X:

- [Install the Metasploit Framework on Apple Mac OS X](https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-1037)
- [Guide to Installing Metasploit 4 and Armitage on Mac OSX Lion](https://www.nightlionsecurity.com/blog/guides/2011/12/guide-to-installing-metasploit-4-and-armitage-on-mac-osx-lion/)
- [How To Install Metasploit Framework In MacOSX](http://www.computersnyou.com/1768/2013/05/how-to-install-metasploit-framework-in-macosx/)

Unfortunately none of these answer to my search, and none lead me to a successfull installation.

---

Do you know a correct and tested receipe to install Metasploit on Mavericks + MacPorts?

Comment: You may want to visit the Apple Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question is much too focused about a "security tool" to interest anyone on apple.stackexchange which I much more than visit :).

Answer (score 2):

## Version used

```
MacOS X        10.9.4
Xcode          5.1.1
MacPorts       2.3.1
Ruby           1.9.3
Postgresql     9.3.5
Metasploit     4.9.3
```

## Method

To avoid any confusion between system, MacPorts and Metasploit binaries
it is fundamental to start to install everything in clearly separate
part of the filesystem.

Here are the choices I took:

```
/local/MacPorts     initial install of MacPorts
/local/Metasploit   install of Metasploit
/opt/local          install of everything managed with MacPorts
```

## Steps

The overall steps to install completly Metasploit are:

1. Xcode + command line tools
2. MacPorts
3. Ruby
4. Postgresql
5. Metasploit

---

## 1. Xcode + command line tools

- Download Xcode 5.1.1 from the App Store (2 Go)
- launch it to check and accept the licence
- install the command line tools with:

  ```
  xcode-select --install
  ```

## 2. MacPorts

- Create the initial directory structure (let's say my account is *BOB*).

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /local/MacPorts
  $ /usr/bin/sudo chown BOB /local/MacPorts
  ```
- Download the latest tarball:

  From [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org):
  [MacPorts 2.3.1](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.1.tar.bz2)
  to save it under:

  ```
  /local/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.1.tar.bz2
  ```
- Extract

  ```
  $ cd /local/MacPorts
  $ tar xvf MacPorts-2.3.1.tar.bz2
  ```
- Configure, install

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /opt/local
  $ cd MacPorts-2.3.1
  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local
  $ /usr/bin/sudo make install
  ```

  `port` isn't in my `PATH`, and this is normal.
- **1st `PATH` switch**

  (I'm using `zsh`) insert within `${HOME}/.profile`, within the section
  which is always run and after any other `PATH` or `MANPATH` definition:

  ```
  PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:${PATH}
  export PATH
  MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
  export MANPATH
  ```

  **`PATH` switch**:

  ```
  $ . ${HOME}/.profile
  ```
- Update MacPorts DB

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo port -d selfupdate
  ```

  `port` in in my `PATH`, and this is normal.

## 3. Ruby

- Download, configure and install `ruby19`

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo port install ruby19
  $ /usr/bin/sudo port select ruby ruby19
  ```

  check that everything is ok thus far:
      $ type ruby
      /opt/local/bin/ruby
      $ ruby --version
      ruby 1.9.3p547 ...
- Download, configure and install `bundler`

  ```
  $ gem install bundler
  ```

## 4. Postgresql

- Download, configure and install `postgresql93`

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo port install postgresql93-server
  ```

  the correct install will display:

```
To create a database instance, after install do
 sudo mkdir -p /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
 sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
 sudo su postgres -c '/opt/local/lib/postgresql93/bin/initdb -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb'
```

Simply run these 3 commands, and on correct DB initialization, `postgresql` will warn you:

```
WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/bin/postgres -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
or
    /opt/local/lib/postgresql93/bin/pg_ctl -D /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb -l logfile start
```

- Use the `launchd` plist installed by `MacPorts` in the right place:

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql93-server.plist
  ```

  check that everything is ok thus far:

  ```
  $ telnet localhost 5432
  Trying ::1...
  Connected to localhost.
  ```

  <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Secure `postgresql` (a vulnerabilities DB should be of very restricted access)

  ```
  $ cd /opt/local/var/db/postgresql93/defaultdb
  ```

  edit `pg_hba.conf` to remove the lines:

  ```
  local   all     all                     trust
  host    all     all     127.0.0.1/32    trust
  host    all     all     ::1/128         trust
  ```

  and replace them with:

  ```
  local   postgres        postgres                trust
  local   msf_db          msf_user                trust
  ```

  Restart `postgresql` in this mode limited in access through UNIX domain socket.

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo launchctl stop org.macports.postgresql93-server
  ```
- Select the correct `postgresql` version

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo port select postgresql postgresql93
  ```
- Configure the Metasploit DB to use

  Let's say the user to use will be `msf_user`,
  with password `pass_pass` and the DB will be `msf_db`.
  Switch to user `postgres`:

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/su postgres
  $ createuser msf_user -p
  Enter password for new role: pass_pass
  Enter it again: pass_pass
  $ createdb -O msf_user msf_db
  ```

  These 2 commands won't display anything, this means everything is OK.

## 5. Metasploit

- Install Metasploit

  ```
  $ /usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /local/Metasploit
  $ /usr/bin/sudo chown BOB /local/Metasploit
  $ cd /local/Metasploit
  $ git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework .
  ```
- **2nd `PATH` switch**

  Insert within `${HOME}/.profile`, within the section
  which is always run and after any other `PATH` or `MANPATH` definition:

  ```
  PATH=/local/Metasploit:${PATH}
  export PATH
  ```

  **`PATH` switch**:

  ```
  $ . ${HOME}/.profile
  ```
- Update `Metasploit`:

  ```
   $ msfupdate
  ```
- Configure the DB access:

  ```
  $ cd /local/Metasploit/config
  $ cp database.yml.example database.yml
  $ vi database.yml
  ```

  to include there this uniq block:

  ```
  production:
    adapter:      postgresql
    database:     msf_db
    username:     msf_user
    password:     pass_pass
    port:         5432
    pool:         75
    timeout:      5
  ```

  To get an automatic connection at each start, include the following line within the `metasploit` initialization script:

  ```
  $ cat >${HOME}/.msf4/msfconsole.rc <<eof
  db_connect -y /local/Metasploit/config/database.yml
  eof
  ```
- Check that everything is working:

  ```
  $ msfconsole
  msf > db_status
  [*] postgresql connected to msf_db
  msf >
  ```
- Help yourself a cup of champaign :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive guide. To install postgreSQL DB, the command should be $ /usr/bin/sudo port install postgresql93-server.