# Copy Metasploit from Linux to Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, metasploit

I'm just wondering is there anyway to move Metasploit framework from Linux to Mac completely and It will be work ?
and if yes , how ?

Comment: This is not a security question. Your best bet may be to ask the metasploit team.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the workspace from the Metasploit installed on Linux, install Metasploit on Mac OS using Carlos Parez's [script](https://github.com/darkoperator/MSF-Installer) or using the method outlined [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56433/how-to-install-metasploit-on-mavericks-macports). Once the installation is complete, import the workspace and you will have all the data (hosts, vulnerability information, looted data, etc) in the new setup.

To export the workspace data, connect to the workspace using the msfconsole `workspace <workspace-name>` command and then run db_export:

```
msf > db_export -f xml -a /root/msf-data.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot do this. The coding is specific to the operating system, Linux and OSX are different. There are two options for you. The first is to go through installing [Metasploit on OSX](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-framewor/) and the other alternative would be for you to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion), or some other virtualization software (Parallels), and install Linux as a guest inside of OSX.

Comment: but, both of them are Unix base, aren't them?if it was windows os your word was right but I think we can do it by some trick maybe !